# How can I make a form appear on top of all other windows?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I make a form appear on top of everything on the desktop, not just forms within my application.  I have spent ages Googling but only found snippets for C++ and older versions of Visual Studio which no longer work.  I know the answer is out there, I must be looking for the wrong thing.

Just to be clear - my project is created within Visual Studio 2012 and it is coded in Visual Basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't found an answer because there is no a failproof answer? For example, what happen when another application decides the same thing?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this thread --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434638/force-window-to-be-above-already-top-most-windows-like-the-task-manager

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Steve said, this work as long as your app is the only one using it:

```
Me.TopMost = True
```

Its a property found in forms. If you are executing this outside a form, use the name of the form, for example `Form1.TopMost = True`.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [some info you may find interesting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) about trying to make a window to be in top of "Top-Most" Windows.

Comment: I thought that only applied to forms within the same application - I was totally wrong! Thanks ever so much, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Setting TopMost to True makes it obsure other windows permanently.  I found if you make it True then False, you'll bring the Form to the top so it is visible, yet other Forms can go over if they are selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.TopMost = True
```

BUT in ACTIVATED  (not in LOAD EVENT)

```
Private Sub frm_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub
```