# WPF Always On Top

Tags: c#, wpf, topmost

Is it possible to make a window stay always on top even when other application is running on Fullscreen? I'm using right now `TopMost = true` but when other application is running on fullscreen mine becomes invisible. It's `WindowStyle = None` window by the way.

**Edit**: And do not let other window minimalize ofcourse

Comment: Which application is running fullscreen? There's a big difference between a maximized window (eg a web browser), and an application that really take over the display (like most videogames by default)

Comment: It depends how **they** implemented full screen feature (did they open a DC for display of they just put their own window on the top, maximized and without borders?). Of course you can always **handle changes in your own window** style to react in the proper way (for example restoring visible state).

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434638/force-window-to-be-above-already-top-most-windows-like-the-task-manager) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066082/how-to-keep-my-topmost-window-on-top) interesting, they are for C++ but the comments are relevant.

Comment: I mean about games. When I run let's say NBA2k13 which I tested before, my application is hidden underneath videogame.

Comment: Don't worry. It's made to be almost invisible when playing. It's hidden on the edge of the screen and you can access the program by going with cursor on this edge. And you can lock it so it won't open, only 21x21px box for unlock. It's a music player btw.

Comment: `Topmost="True"` is also very useful in debugging with visual studio.

Answer (score 65):

This won't work 100% of the time, but it will improve the situation somewhat. You can set `Topmost = true` in the handler for the [`Window.Deactivated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = (Window)sender;
    window.Topmost = true;
}
```

The `Deactivated` event will be called whenever your application loses focus (often when another application requests to be `Topmost`) and so this will reset your application on top after this.

Comment: @Steve, the last focused of the two applications will win (be on top).

Comment: @Sheridan based on what you said, the event will be called whenever it loses focus. So this is a potential infinite loop if more than one application tries to do this?

Comment: No, I see what you mean, but I've never experienced any issues like that.

Comment: @Steve I know this is a few years too late, but here is an interesting article in regard to your question: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413

Comment: I know I'm commenting on an old question/answer, but wanted to add "me too" in addition to others that this doesn't work for - but only on certain systems.  Wondering if there is a system policy that can be set to nullify this as an explanation why my code works on some systems and not others.

Comment: This can also be set in XAML:  <Window ... Topmost="True">

Answer (score 17):

Try this solution from MSDN, it should work for you.
In the `Window Activated Event` add the following code:

```
this.Width   = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
this.Height  = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
this.Topmost = true;
this.Top  = 0;
this.Left = 0;
```

in `DeActivated Event` add the following code

```
this.Topmost = true;
this.Activate();
```

[Original post from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/697915fe-7cc2-4c6f-8f96-ecc6a4924858/always-on-top-even-in-fullscreengames?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 16):

None of the solutions above for me worked, so here is what I ended up doing. It worked perfectly for me.

Basically, to keep it on top you just set the lose focus event to make it go back to top.

XAML:

```
PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="Window_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus"
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Window_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
      var window = (Window)sender;
      window.Topmost = true;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Simple solution, thanks!

Comment: doesnt work for full screen game in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your application to stay on top of EVERYTHING (including the start interface in Windows 8, previously known as "Metro"), then you can specify UiAccess="True" in your manifest file. This is typically used by accessibility applications such as onscreen keyboards.

From memory you need to do 3 things;

1. Request UiAccess="True"
2. Sign your application's exe file with a recognised certificate. I obtained a free code signing certificate from Certum as my project is Open Source.
3. Install your application to a "Trusted Location", which in my case was the program files directory. There is no official definition of "Trusted Location" that I could find.

Comment: Note the manifest file doesn't exist by default; you have to create it (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406789/2317712 )

Comment: More specific "Trusted Locations" and some more official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations

Comment: Certum is not free anymore. You can use a self-signed certificate instead if it meets your needs, I explained the whole thing in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547061/11982162

Answer (score 3):

So I ran into the same requirement recently. It seems the top rated answer as well as the second didn't properly work for me. I've found a solution that seems to work flawlessly and somewhat adheres to best practice using MVVM.

Using the below forces the window to the top and never lapses on change like the other solutions.

Step 1: I created a simple state manager class for my main client window. I used INotifyPropertyChanged to keep property in sync when using a direct binding to my window. (very important)

```
public class ClientStateManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Private Variables
    private bool isForceToTop;
    private bool isClientEnabled;
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public bool IsForceToTop
    {
        get { return isForceToTop; }
        set
        {
            isForceToTop = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool IsClientEnabled
    {
        get { return isClientEnabled; }
        set
        {
            isClientEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }       
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void Lock() => this.IsClientEnabled = false;
    public void UnLock() => this.IsClientEnabled = true;
    public void SetTop() => this.IsForceToTop = true;
    public void UnSetTop() => this.IsForceToTop = false;
    #endregion

    #region Public Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    #endregion
}
```

Step 2.1: Added my state manager class to my ViewModel. (MVVM)

```
  internal class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    #region Constructor
    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        ClientStateManager = new ClientStateManager();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties  
    public ClientStateManager ClientStateManager { get; private set; }
    #endregion
  }
```

Step 2.2: Then set your window data context to your view model.

```
  private MainWindowViewModel model;
  private MainWindow()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.model = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = model;
  }
```

Step 3: Add your data binding to your window.

```
  <Window x:Class="Intouch_Work.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ojects="clr-namespace:Framework.Object;assembly=Framework"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"     
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Intouch" Height="800" Width="1100"
    x:Name="mainWindow"
    Topmost="{Binding Path=ClientStateManager.IsForceToTop, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

So now you can manage your window state using the state manager object initialized within the View Model. You can call SetTop() from you state manager to push it forward, or UnSetTop() to stop it.
Hope this helps anyone looking to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar for an industrial quality control application, where non-admin operators should not be able to minimize or use anything else on the dedicated computer while the application is running, not even `Windows+D` to bring up the desktop. And I found out that the cleanest and simplest way to achieve that is through:

1. Settings the correct `Width`, `Height`, `WindowStyle`, `WindowState` and `Topmost` properties.
2. Handling some related events: `StateChanged`, `Deactivated`, `LostFocuse`, `LostMouseCapture`, `LostKeyboardFocus` and `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus`.
3. Handling closing events with `ALT+F4` or a custom button).

No need for P/Invoke, Here is the full code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            Closing += OnClosing;
            StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
            Deactivated += (sender, args) => Activate();
            LostFocus += (sender, args) => Focus();
            LostMouseCapture += (sender, args) => Mouse.Capture(this);
            LostKeyboardFocus += (sender, args) => Keyboard.Focus(this);
            PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += (sender, args) => Keyboard.Focus(this);
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            Topmost = true;
            // Other stuff here
        }

        private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // You might want to allow only some users to close the app
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you an admin?", "Admin Check", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.No)
               e.Cancel = true;
        }

        private void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

You can also put some of this in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FullScreen.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStyle="None" 
        Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a main window that I wanted to keep on top of everything (if the user checked "always on top".
This worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

```
// If we want main to stay on top, we set the rest of the menus to Not be top 
if (mnuViewMainWindowAlwaysOnTopo.IsChecked)
{
    this.Topmost = true;
    
    foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
        // Don't change for main window
        if (window.GetType().Name != this.GetType().Name)
            window.Topmost = false;
}
else this.Topmost = false;
```