# Make a Form "more TopMost" than another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, topmost

I have a **WinForms** application with 2 Forms. Both are `TopMost`, but I would want to have one of them to always be on top of the second one.

It's something like **"even more `TopMost`**.

**Is this possible?**

Calling `BringToFront()` in a timer causes the form to flicker.

Comment: Raymond Chen's response is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: @GrantWinney: I'm going to guess they want it to *stay* topmost. Calling `BringToFront` will only keep it topmost until the other form gets clicked and pulled to the front. Not to say it's still not a horrible way to solve the problem.

Comment: @GrantWinney Both windows are TopMost, but one needs to be even more, like described. I have to call `BringToFront()` for the lower topmost window in a timer, too. This is in order to avoid other windows popping in front of it.

Comment: You should be able to fire a method (like `BringToFront`) when the second form is clicked to focus the first form again.

Comment: @adv12 Its not that he wants both to be the top most, he wants one to be top most and the other to be 2nd from top most. But there is no `SecondFromTopMost = true` in winforms.

Comment: @EBrown This would work in a casual situation, but the form in the background acts as a screen overlay which lets the user "click-through", if you know what I mean.

Comment: You may have to rethink your design because I don't think this is possible for reason alluded to in the link @adv12 posted. Even adding more levels of *topmostness* just shifts the problem around. How many levels are enough? If the background form is a screen overlay, as you say, is it fullscreen? Could you make the *topmostest* form just be a child of that form so it'll always be above it?

Comment: Set Topmost property of one form to false. It will always be behind the one which has TopMost set to true.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I think the OP wants the non-topmost form to still be topmost to *everything else*, however.

Comment: The problem with `TopMost` is how does Windows decide what is *ultimately* `TopMost`? Does your application take precedence because the name starts with an `A` instead of a `D`, or does the other application take precedence because it has a lower `GUID` in the identifier, or a shorter filename? Additionally, if Windows *could* decide who gets to be `TopMost` ultimately, what happens when application `A` uses some hack to make Windows make it the `TopMostest`, and application `B` uses the same hack? If your design requires `TopMost` functionality, I recommend you reevaluate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [SetWindowPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx).

It might be helpful.

---

**EDIT:**

After reviewing these answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434638/force-window-to-be-above-already-top-most-windows-like-the-task-manager), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066082/how-to-keep-my-topmost-window-on-top), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net/683346#683346)), it's not possible to do such thing.

Comment: This is good. I tried `HWND_NOTOPMOST`, but that allows other windows to overlap it.

Comment: @bytecode77 - Answer updated. Unfortunately, there's no way to do what you're looking for.